# jQuery add selected to option after post data

Tags: javascript, jquery

I add `json` data into `option` `data-values`
In action when I click on `option`, my jQuery code add `data-values` data to option list in `#target` using `JSON.parse`, `each`, and `append` methods.

```js
$('#list').change(function() {
  var response = JSON.parse($(this).find(':selected').attr('data-values'));
  var len = response.length;
  $("#target").empty();
  $.each(response, function() {
    $.each(this, function(name, value) {
      $("#target").append("<option value='" + name + "'>" + value + "</option>");
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="list">
  <optgroup label="Hardware">
    <option value="5" data-values='[{"34":"500GB","35":"1TB","36":"2TB","37":"4TB"}]'>
      HDD
    </option>
    <option value="11" data-values='[{"63":"Ardreno 650","64":"Adreno 640","65":"NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650","66":"NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1080","67":"NVIDIA GeForce GTX 2070","68":"NVIDIA GeForce GTX 2080"}]' selected="selected">
      Graphics
    </option>
  </optgroup>
</select>

<select id="target"></select>
```

Now, in `create page` my code work true, But I have a big problem in post back. When I send data to my `php` controller and my controller return any error, I need to add `old` select data (send data) into `#target` list. Actually I need to auto load `#target` list on page load if `#list` option is `selected` and add `selected` to `#target` option list.

[Worked demo](https://jsfiddle.net/cnp7yoz1/1/)

[Doesn't work demo](https://jsfiddle.net/cnp7yoz1/2/) (add selected to option)

Comment: Why use data attr at all. Just have an object where the key matches the value of the option

Comment: Just add `$('#list').change();`. [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/cd2b1k9u/). However, this will not reselect the selected option of the second dropdown.

Comment: `$('#list').on("change",function() { ... }).change();`

Comment: @mplungjan: Sure u right. thanks. but how do find `#target` option selected? ie: I send `1TB` and `2TB` for `HDD`. when I `chenge()` `#list` I see only `HDD` list. the bigger problem is here. `change()` load only `#target` list and I don't know, how do selected options in `#target` list using `change()`.

Comment: Then you need to set the value or the selectedIndex using localStorage if you cannot set it on the object from the server

Comment: @mplungjan: your mean is set back data to `json` object for example? and then add to option list?

Comment: Something like

`const data = { "5": [{"34":{ "500GB", "selected":true},{"35":"1TB"},{"36":"2TB"},{"37":"4TB"}}]`

Comment: @mplungjan: great. please add to answer to select it. if you have more time can u tell me how do work with your object for selected target list? I need to new function? or modify my function with 'change()' method? thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Try this: `$('#list').trigger('change');`